# Validate Standard Numeric Format

Tags: vb.net, validation, number-formatting

I have a Problem with validating a String in vb.net.

I want to check if the inputString is in a valid standard numeric Format according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx except "E" and "X"

So i have the Format specifier e.g. "d4" and my inputString like "1999". But the Specifier is unknown at design time.

Is there a way to validate the inputString if it is valid with the given Format specifier

greetz gangfish

UPDATE:

I am writing an Extension for a working programm. 
I am adding massprocessing for selected rows from a gridview.

If a row is selected, the values are shown in my inputFields. 
The inputFields are from Telerik UI for WinForms(RadMaskedEditBox).

If multiple rows are selected, i have to remove the Masking, because we have to add an Editor-Pattern for alle Entries (Form: {1..5}*test*).

So i have to validate if the given input is valid for the masking assigned by the main application. So i have no clue what format specifier is given at design time.

But i know that all standard numeric formats except "E" and "X" are supported by the RadMaskedEditBox

I would like to have something like this:

```
Dim inputValue = "1999"
Dim formatSpecifier = "d4"
Try
    ValidateValue(inputValue, formatSpecifier)
Catch ex As Exception
    ' Validation Failed. Handle it
End Try
```

Comment: That's not clear: _"So i have the Format specifier ... but the Specifier is unknown at design time.

Is there a way to validate the inputString if it is valid with the given Format specifier?"_. Do you have it or not, can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

A format specifier is just a string.  You can substitute it with any string value at runtime, provided that string value is a valid format specifier.  (Otherwise I imagine you'll get an error, so you'll want to have some error handling around all of this.)

For example, given the sample code on the link you provided:

```
decimal value = 123.456m;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C2"));
```

If you have a format specifier obtained from somewhere else and stored in a string variable, you can just use that variable:

```
string formatSpecifier = GetFormatSpecifier();
// ...
decimal value = 123.456m;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(formatSpecifier));
```

Or if it's part of a larger string, you can just concatenate it into that string.  So where you would normally have this:

```
decimal value = 123.456m;
Console.WriteLine("Your account balance is {0:C2}.", value);
```

You might instead have this:

```
string formatSpecifier = GetFormatSpecifier();
// ...
decimal value = 123.456m;
Console.WriteLine("Your account balance is " + formatSpecifier + ".", value);
```

(Or you can construct the string with a `StringBuilder`.  You might also use `string.Format()` to assemble your format specifier, but I imagine that could introduce confusion when supporting that code.)

Comment: my input value is a string, no decimal or floating or something else. It will be a String every time i want to validate this Value. So i dont see, how this could help me, or am i missing something?

Comment: @gangfish: These are just examples (from the link you provided), they're not meant to be pasted directly into your code.  The point is that a format specifier is itself just a string, so you can use any runtime string you have as a format specifier.